# How to check list A not contains any elemnt from list B

Tags: c#, list, linq, contains

I want to return a list object, where is any difference in value on any element in **productFromSqls**.
I try to do this way but doesn't work.

```
var result = productFromSqls.Where(
            x => !productFromApis.Any(y => y.id == x.idshop))
            .ToList();
```

Example should return ProductFromSql id=1 and id=2

**Model**

```
public class ProductFromSql
{
    public string idEshop { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }

    public string code { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}


public class ProductFromApi
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }

    public string code { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string  man_code  { get; set; }
}
```

**List**

```
public static void NotEquals()
{

    var productFromSqls = new List<ProductFromSql> {
            new ProductFromSql {idEshop="1", active="0",code="2dw",amount="22",description="testowy opis"},
            new ProductFromSql {idEshop="2", active="1",code="kk34",amount="11",description="testowy opis 2"},
            new ProductFromSql {idEshop="3", active="0",code="2323",amount="22",description="testowy opis 3"} 
    };

    var productFromApis = new List<ProductFromApi> {
            new ProductFromApi {id="1", active="1",code="2dw",amount="22",description="testowy opis",createDate="20180312",updated_at="20170419",man_code="AA2"},
            new ProductFromApi {id="2", active="1",code="kk34",amount="33",description="testowy opis 2",createDate="20180322",updated_at="20170412",man_code="AA4"},
            new ProductFromApi {id="3", active="0",code="2323",amount="22",description="testowy opis 3",createDate="20180311",updated_at="20170402",man_code="BA4"}
    };

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the `.Except(...)` linq operator?

Comment: Since they're all string, concatenate them all and check that if it's different

Comment: When try var result = productFromSqls.Where(x => !productFromApis.Except(y => y.id == x.idEshop)).ToList(); I get error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable<ProductFromApi>' because it is not a delegate type" .Sorry only my example have only string type .Normal API back  other type value

Comment: @derloopkat If I remove **!** I get all objects where id=idshop and return 3 object. I want to connect object from to list by id and check if some element is different then put into new list.Solution below is  exactly my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the properties which you want to compare.

```
var result = productFromSqls.Where(x => !productFromApis.Any(y => y.id == x.idEshop
                                                               && y.active == x.active
                                                               && y.code == x.code
                                                               && y.amount == x.amount
                                                               && y.description == x.description)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method which will compare all elements form the object which are common in both of the classes

```
List<ProductFromSql> Filtered = new List<ProductFromSql>();

productFromSqls.ForEach(x => productFromApis.ForEach(ele => 
                             {
                                if(!AreObjectsEqual(x, ele) && !Filtered.Any(ele => ele.id == x.id)) 
                                    Filtered.Add(x);  
                             }));


public bool AreObjectsEqual(ProductFromSql obj1, ProductFromApi obj2)
{
   return (obj1.id == obj2.idEshop && obj1.active == obj2.active)//......) //Add other properties of your class which are common in both in ........
}
```

Comment: Solution don't work.Result is wrong. Filtered list has repeat objects.